# How to clear input and ask for password again?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get a password from a user using a function.

**The expectation:** When a user presses  <kbd>Enter</kbd> and there's no input, nothing should happen.

**The actual behaviour:** When a user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the cursor goes to the next line and when the user enters some characters and presses  <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, I get this:

```
Password=xyz
xyz
xyz
```

**Here's the function:**

```
get_password () {
  read -s
  if [ -z $REPLY ]; then
    get_password
  fi
  echo $REPLY
}

$PASSWORD=$(get_password)
echo "Password $PASSWORD"
```

Please help me improve this function

Comment: It is always very wise to read to first 5 points in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/069

Comment: @kvantour, man... I can't thank you enough. I was under the impression that it's okay to pass sensitive data via env variables. You're a life saver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where almost there.

```sh
get_password () {
    read -s -p "password? " REPLY;
    echo
    if [[ -z $REPLY ]]; then
        get_password;
    else
        echo $REPLY;
    fi;
}
```

Output:

```
 $ get_password
password? 
password? 
password?              # Here I typed "test"
test
$ PASSWORD="$(get_password)"
password?
$ echo $PASSWORD
a password
```

EDIT: Added saving password in variable.